# Caroufredsel image gallery with a horizontal thumbnail carousel

Tags: jquery, carousel, caroufredsel

I am using this script, but it doesn't work when my gallery has only 3 images (the thumbnails do nothing):

http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/26/

Which part of the script should I alter to get rid of the scrolling and have a simple show/hide when I have 3 or less images?

Thanks!

Comment: could you please set up a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net) ? and post here the relevant `html` and `JS`

Comment: @Spokey sure, I set one up here: http://jsfiddle.net/chorvat/fAjFS/ I set up the working carousel, and need to figure out how to not break it when it gets down to two thumbnails. Scroll past all the packed javascript to get to the applicable part.

Comment: do you want this plugin only for 3 images ? or do you use it somewhere else for more images?

Comment: I am using it elsewhere for more images, but have one page that is only 3. I could set up a different carousel there, but preferred to be consistent if possible.